# How to count empty rows in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

In my postgresql query given below and I want to `count(completed::float)`

```
select round(Count(completed::float)) as completed,
       assignee 
from NTE_23Apr19_HCMS_DOW_Defects_List_V1 
group by assignee
```

This is my postgresql table

[image]

If I used without **float** in query it will works but I want to execute with float.Is It possible

```
select round(Count(completed)) as completed,
       assignee 
from NTE_23Apr19_HCMS_DOW_Defects_List_V1 
group by assignee
```

Comment: `count(completed)` and `count(completed::float)` or even `count(completed)::float` will all return the same value. What exactly are you trying to do? Maybe you just want `count(*)`?

Comment: If I used count(completed)::float instead of count(completed::float).It works

Comment: Then I have no idea what you are trying to do. `count` returns an integer, casting that integer to float won't change its value. And counting float values won't return a different count that counting integer values. What exactly does "it works" mean? Do you get an error if it does "not work"? Is your screen shot the result you get or the result you expect?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which should consist of a `create table` statement, some `insert` statements and the **expected** output as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please. **[edit]** your question do **not** post code in comments

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as an empty row in PostgreSQL.
Your value is either '' (empty string), or a `NULL` value.
You can count those the following ways:

`sum(case when completed = '' then 1 else 0 end)`

`sum(case when completed is null then 1 else 0 end)`

better yet:

`sum(case when coalesce(completed,'') = '' then 1 else 0 end)` - which will cover both situations.

Comment: I want count(decimal),sum(int),avg(float) in above table.If anyone knows please guide me.

Comment: You're going to have to add your desired results to your question.